# Burninate [derived]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request

There's <s>204</s> 205 questions tagged with [derived](/questions/tagged/derived). It has no wiki, no synonyms, and I feel it doesn't really add any value.

There are also:

- [derived-class](/questions/tagged/derived-class) x 365
- [derived-table](/questions/tagged/derived-table) x 52
- [derived-types](/questions/tagged/derived-types) x 43
- [derived-instances](/questions/tagged/derived-instances) x 9
- [derived-works](/questions/tagged/derived-works) x 5

I lack the super powers to accomplish this by my lonesome self.