# Let's burn English

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[english](/questions/tagged/english)

A [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772908/english-which-sentence-is-grammatically-correct-and-why) introduced me to the English tag.  It appears to be a fount of off topic and crap.  I wish to make the tag suffer for this.  What say you, grumps?

[image]

Okay, yeah, stupid question.  Let's burn it.

Comment: All hail our Kitty Overlords! But really, what's a "font of off-topic and crap"?

Comment: Are you hovering in the incineratocopter?

Comment: @animuson: Not sure what you're talking about.  It's clearly "fount".  Sheesh.

Comment: @Won't That's exactly why they have the tag :D

Comment: -1 for use of an over-used meme that wasn't funny to begin with.

Comment: -1 on comments that indicate downvotes that actually didn't happen

Comment: English is certainly overrated. As indicated by many SO questions.

Comment: I didn't say I was downvoting anything, but thanks for playing!

Comment: @JohnnyBones: Now I'm confused. What does +1/-1 mean then?

Comment: It means different things on SO vs SE.  ;o)

Comment: +1/-1 means "confused."

Comment: I think that means NULL, right? I don't know, it's been a while since I took a Math class.

Comment: @JohnnyBones If a Won't post didn't include an overused meme that wasn't funny to begin with, I'd assume the account was hacked

Comment: But hey, at lesat that tag wiki is *informative*.

Comment: Not satisfied with burning all `[books]`, now you're going after an entire language?  When will this madness stop?!

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Oh, right about after I burn down [hot-topic].

Comment: @Won't - the store or the tag?

Comment: @JohnnyBones +1/-1 evaluates to -1, AFAIK. (In the plain old real numbers, anyway.)

Comment: @michaelb958 "plain old _real_ numbers"? +1/-1 is -1 in IEE 758 _floating point_ also

Comment: @ColeJohnson Oops, and even in integers...

Comment: Oh, right!  -1/+1 would be NULL.  It all comes back to me now...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just six days short of its fifth birthday, the [english](/questions/tagged/english) tag on Stack Overflow is no more.

[image: Burninated]

Comment: Wait... you have a magic burn button?  Or was that manual?

Comment: As long as you're in the mood..  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196719/burninate-derived

Comment: I really feel like this was done too quickly. Honestly, there is no discussion in this question... Please see my recent answer on [What does the English (or other spoken language) tag tell about a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190728/7586) , where I *think* I have some good usages for language tags.

Comment: There are certainly valid uses for language tags, @Kobi. However, this one did not appear to be widely used for such purposes.

Comment: @Shog9 So, what will replace it for the valid purposes??

Comment: If there are any valid purposes that need to be tagged "english", it can be re-created @Bobble - I have my doubts though, given the age of the tag and the small number of questions using it.